# Can I render ui-router nested views side by side?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router for navigation in an angular app. I use nested states/views in a hierarchy like this.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<h1>Page Title</h1>
<ui-view></ui-view>

<!-- Page1.template.html -->
<h1>Title 1</h1>
<ui-view></ui-view>

<!-- Page2.template.html -->
<h1>Title 2</h1>
<ui-view></ui-view>

<!-- Page3.template.html -->
<h1>Title 3</h1>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

This result in as expected like this:

[image]

Is it possible to make the page look like this instead, i.e. render child views side by side:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Take a look at the docs - [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views). Basically you would have your page like:

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="child1"></div>
    <div ui-view="child2"></div>
    <div ui-view="child3"></div>
</body>
```

and a state config

```
$stateProvider
.state('main',{
    views: {
        'child1': {
            templateUrl: 'child1.html',
            controller: 'Child1Ctrl'
        },
        'child1': {
             templateUrl: 'child2.html',
             controller: 'Child2Ctrl'
        },
        'child3': {
            templateUrl: 'child3.html',
            controller: 'Child3Ctrl'
        }
    }
});
```

Each child view can have it's own configuration, the same as original state configs.

Update:

If you want them to be dynamic i.e. specify views you want to render manually, going with this approach you could specify names in some `$scope` variable and `ng-repeat` over them:

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.views = ['child1', 'child3'];

})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="view in views">

    <div ui-view="{{view}}"></div>

</div>
```

See an example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/wVmR6q1UXqhNsF8afpd2?p=preview

Comment: Can I make this more dynamic? I don't want to have a fixed number of child views.